# Juniper EX4500 selective q-in-q

Tags: juniper, juniper-ex, qinq

This switch supports selective qinq?
For example I got 3 vlans on client port: 100, 200, 300.
I need to add second tag on vlans 100, 200 but vlan 300 must run as is, without adding second tag.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is supported - please see the answer here (for EX4200, but same behaviour can be expected on EX4550):

[Juniper EX4200 QinQ question](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/56968/juniper-ex4200-qinq-question/57036#57036)